# Using Prebuilt library in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface, boringssl

I'm making a jni Function in android to generate file checkSum using BoringSSL.

So I built boringssl to shared Library for use Prebuilt Library in Android studio.

The build output like this.
[image]

I copied the *.so file to my project src/main/jniLibs/lib 
and BoringSSL include folder to src/main/jni

I referenced this project and apply to my projects.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs

My **build.gradle** file like this.
I'm using gradle-experimental:0.7.0( and Window10, Android Studio 2.1.2 )

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            boringssl {
                headers.srcDir "src/main/jni/include/openssl"

                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/lib/libcrypto.so")
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/lib/libssl.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 24
        buildToolsVersion = '24.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = 'yein.a'
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = '1.0'
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName = 'hello-libs'
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
        }
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library 'boringssl' linkage 'shared'
                    }
                }
                jniLibs{
                    source{
                        srcDir "src/main/jniLibs/lib"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        productFlavors{
            create("arm"){
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

This is my project structure.

[image]

I think I properly apply the example projects, because it is not occurred gradle sync error.

And when I use MD5 function Android Studio auto complete function name like this.
[image]

But I click run it occurred error like this...
[image]

I searched a lot project in google,github, and of course stackoverflow previous answers but I still not solve my problem.

I tried change gradle version but other gradle version occurred error in auto generated jni function except gradle-experimental:0.7.0.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or even a solution?

Thanks for read my Question.

Comment: Hi @심예인
I have problem like you too. Do you resolve it? Could you share for me your simple example project? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @PhanSinh I just put my source code on Github [link](https://github.com/yein28/Checksum) This project is get md5 value of My APK file. I wrote this code few months ago. few month ago, it works fine but I'm not sure it still works fine. I hope this code helpful for you :)

Comment: THanks so much @심예인.
I'm using OpenSSl for AES to encrypt my data. But now I found that Google use BoringSSL instead for OpenSSl from Android 6. Do you know? Did you worked with BoringSSL?

Comment: @PhanSinh Yes I build BoringSSL library and apply my project. I left my github repo in the comment that's the example I worked whit BoringSSL!

Comment: How do you build include openssl lib? I refer this guide https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android but it's not work. Have you facebook or skype? Can I ask you more?

Comment: @PhanSinh I know Android doesn't support OpenSSL anymore.. Have you seen "https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/" building.md ? It's include How to build BoringSSL for Android.

Comment: Thanks.
Do you know php? Now hava problem with encryption between java and php not match :( I use AES/CBC/PCSK5Padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to call the java API from JNI, there is a nice tutorial [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-5.), Google recommends on this [site](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) you should call the java API or you can link the libraries as you did.

If you can't or don't want to call the java API you can always use CRC32 instead of MD5, CRC32 uses the libz library and that library is already on the NDK files. CRC32 in C.

```
#include <zlib.h>

int checkSumCRC32(char *text){
    long n = crc32(0, (const void*)text, strlen(text));
    printf("CRC32 %d", n);
    return n;
}
```

Remember to add `ldLibs.addAll(['z'])` to your Gradle file

In case you need MD5 and BoringSSL this is my gradle.build file for BoringSSL.

Note: I am using the 3 libraries you compile on ubuntu, libssl.a libcrypto.a and libdecrepit.a

Note2: `I am using com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            libcrypto {
                headers.srcDir "./main/jni/include/openssl"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/${targetPlatform.getName()}/crypto/libcrypto.a")
                }
            }
            libssl {
                headers.srcDir "./main/jni/include/openssl"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/${targetPlatform.getName()}/ssl/libssl.a")
                }
            }
           libdecrepit {
                headers.srcDir "src/main/jni/include/openssl"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/${targetPlatform.getName()}/decrepit/libdecrepit.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "net.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
        }
        ndk {
            platformVersion = 21
            moduleName = "modulename"
            toolchain = "clang"
            abiFilters.addAll([ 'armeabi-v7a'])
            CFlags.addAll(["-fvisibility=hidden", "-fpic"])
            ldLibs.addAll(['log', 'z', 'android']) //Libreria llog, lz y landroid

        }

        sources {
            main {
                jni{
                    dependencies {
                         library "libcrypto" linkage "static"
                         library "libssl" linkage "static"
                         library "libdecrepit" linkage "static"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

I haven't used MD5 but I have used SHA256 using boringSSL and it works fine. You can use it too as a checksum method. This is my method for SHA256.

```
char *sha256(char *str){
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char *output = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*((SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2)+1));
    if (output == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, str, strlen(str));
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){

       sprintf(&output[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)hash[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```